# Add android-like governors to any Linux on PC

Tags: linux, cpufreq

I was looking for a better way to get the most of a laptop on Ubuntu or any Linux distro. In Android rooted phones, we can add CPU governors to the kernel in order to have "smart governors" taking advantage of the multi-core architecture and the downclock abilities of a CPU. These governors can give the user the best user experience while keeping the lowest heating/power consumption. 
Unfortunately, I can't find anywhere if there is a possible way to get one of those "android governors" to work with computers Linux Distros.

More about :

- [Android's Kernel CPU Governors.](http://wiki.rootzwiki.com/CPU_Governors)
- [CPU frequency scaling.](https://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/CpuFrequencyScaling)
- [CPU freq default Linux Governors.](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/cpu-freq/governors.txt)

PS: I am fully aware of the archicatural difference between ARM processors and x86 and others, latest x86 processors have features like p-state for example that are somewhat like what Arms are offering.

Answer (score 1):

I just browsed the documentation, so not an expert. But your concerns about x86 vs ARM are irrelevant. Governors set policy, they don't execute it. That's the job of the CPUfreq driver. Your laptop should already have a suitable driver, for sleep purposes.

I.e. you should be able to compile any "Android" CPU governor for x86 and have it talk to your CPUfreq driver.

Comment: Yes, I already know about that since as you explained, we can compile those governors for the two architectures (and I think it's obvious because there are both android for ARM and x86 tablets/phones). What I find currently strange is that no one ported actually those governors to the actual pc platform. I wonder if that was ever tested.